# Horizontal space problem when the float environment isn't used

Tags: floats

In fact, I want to have a horizontal space after a section, but the problem is when I include an image without using float environment there is no horizontal space. Here are the captions:
When the image isn't used everything is fine
[image]
When the image is used :
[image]

Here is the code that I used, the reason why I included those packages is to show if the use of a package might be the main cause for this no space alignment:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, nccmath}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1.6em}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Section 1}
This first section concernes ....
%\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}}
\captionof{table}{Caption of IMAGE 1}
%\begin{tabular}
%\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.450]{caption of image}
\end{center}
\subsection{Section 2}
This section 2 concerns.....
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put a caption outside a proper environment (as the warning says). Using it inside a table environment, results in

[image: result]

with the following code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, nccmath}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1.6em}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}


\begin{document}
\subsection{Section 1}
This first section concerns\dots
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Caption of IMAGE 1}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.450]{example-image}
\end{table}

\subsection{Section 2}
This section 2 concerns.....
\end{document}
```